# How to query nested json data in linq?

Tags: .net, api, linq, asp.net-core

I am able to query by passing "name": "Test" in postman post(api calls).
But when i tried to pass "data.Status":"success" in postman post...i am unable to filter the data when i used nested json data.
Can you please let me know a way to query nested json data?

Result expected:
I should get the 2nd item from cosmos db as i am filtering on "data.Status":"success"

Cosmos db data:
1st item:

```
{
    "id": "fe5",
    "name": "Test",
    "clientId": 50000,
    "data": {
        "Id": "3D",
        "Status": "success1"
    }
}
```

2nd item:

```
    {
        "id": "fe",
        "name": "Test1",
        "clientId": 50000,
        "data": {
            "Id": "3DA",
            "Status": "success"
        }
    }
```

Model.cs:

```
 public class Job
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        public JObject Data { get; set; }
    }
Filter query:
public async Task<List<Models.Job>> GetJobsByFilter(Dictionary<string, string> filters)
{
            var allJobsQueryable = _jobsRepo.GetAllJobs();
            var jobModelConversions = GetJobModelConversionExpressions();

            foreach (var key in filters.Keys)
            {
                var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Models.Job), key);
                var keyPropExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, key);---------------- problem is here: unable to get the model property for json nested data(data.success ) is failing

                if (!jobModelConversions.ContainsKey(keyPropExpr.Type))
                    throw new Exception("Unknown type : " + keyPropExpr.Type.ToString());

                var typeDelegate = jobModelConversions[keyPropExpr.Type];
                var constantExp = typeDelegate(filters[key]);

                var eqExpr = Expression.Equal(keyPropExpr, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(constantExp), keyPropExpr.Type));
                var condExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Models.Job, bool>>(eqExpr, paramExpr);
                allJobsQueryable = (IOrderedQueryable<Models.Job>) allJobsQueryable.Where(condExpr);
            }

            return allJobsQueryable.ToList();
        }


 public Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> GetJobModelConversionExpressions()
        {
            var lookup = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>();

            lookup.Add(typeof(string), x => { return x; });
            lookup.Add(typeof(int), x => { return int.Parse(x); });
            lookup.Add(typeof(int?), x => { return int.Parse(x); });

            return lookup;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

cast the json to an object then use `SelectTokens` to get at what you want.

```
SelectMany(tr => tr.SelectTokens("data.status", false)).Select(t => t.Value<string>()).ToArray();
```

Just set your array variable up to receive that result, then you can of course get the first, second, whatever you want.

Comment: you can mark your self answer to end this question.:)